# Asynchronous python functions in Visual Studio Code and Azure

Tags: python, azure, http, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am creating an Azure function using Visual Studio Code and python. I need the function to immediately return an http 204 code (successful) as soon as the user passes in a parameter. After the initial 204 response, I need the function to continue processing until completion. No further http responses are required.

The general project structure is as follows:

```
def process():
   # do stuff


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
   return func.HttpResponse(status_code=204)
   # run process() function
```

It is very important the the code runs in this order. The process() method takes anywhere from 5-10 minutes to run but my client's API needs an immediate response from the function saying, effectively, "the processing has started successfully." Once again, no further http codes / responses are required after the initial, immediate 204.

I have tried to work with python's *asyncio* library but have so far found nothing that will help my case. I have also tried the *bottle* framework with no solution.

Comment: I have not used Azure functions so I'm not sure if this suggestion would work, but take a look at Celery to see if that could solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Durable Functions, specifically the [Async HTTP APIs pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python#async-http). Also, the **202 Accepted** code looks more appropriate in your situation.